# Update database with onClick (NewB)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Thanks for the help mighty Johan. but I cant get get my db to update. If you do have time please look over my two files and tell me what the F is wrong
 my hire_staff.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("header.php");
?>
<?php
$chief_aerodynamicist = $staff['chief_aerodynamicist'];
$chief_designer = $staff['chief_designer'];
$commercial_director = $staff['commercial_director'];
$pit_crew = $staff['pit_crew'];
$technical_director = $staff['technical_director'];




?>
<head>
<script>
function bye(){
    alert('bye');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    function hire(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {uid: 12341234}, //this sends the user-id to php as a post variable, in php it can be accessed as $_POST['uid']
            success: function(data){
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                //update some fields with the updated data
                //you can access the data like 'data["driver"]'
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
</head>

<center><h2>You can hire new staff here</h2></center>

<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td>Chief Aerodynamicist:</td>
            <td><i><?php echo "Level $chief_aerodynamicist"; ?></i></td>
            <td><form><input type="button" value="Hire!" onClick="hire();"</form></td>
        </tr>
          <tr>   
            <td>Chief Designer:</td>
            <td><i><?php echo "Level $chief_designer"; ?></i></td>
        </tr>
          <tr>               
            <td>Commercial Director:</td>
            <td><i><?php echo "Level $commercial_director"; ?></i></td>
        </tr>
          <tr>  
            <td>Pit Crew:</td>
            <td><i><?php echo "Level $pit_crew"; ?></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td>Technical Director:</td>
            <td><i><?php echo "Level $technical_director"; ?></i></td>
        </tr>


</table>



<?php
include("footer.php");
?>
```

My test1.php file

```
<?php
include("functions.php");
connect();
if(isset($_POST['uid'])){
     connect();
    mysql_query("UPDATE  `staff` SET  `driver` =  '3' WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['uid']."'") or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT FROM `staff` WHERE `id`='".$_POST['uid']."'")or die(mysql_error());
    $results = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo json_encode($results);

}

?>
```

its actually the staff in the 's that I want to update but driver is also in the same table

Comment: Please accept the answer that helped you solve your problem, and if it still persists, please comment

Comment: Just a headsup that `mysql`functions are depricated and the use of `mysqli` / `pdo` are the way to go nowadays.

Comment: url: "update.php", is  url: "test1.php", sorry

Comment: I see now also you try to open your connection twice, just once will suffice in your test1.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {uid: 12341234}, //this sends the user-id to php as a post variable, in php it can be accessed as $_POST['uid']
            success: function(data){
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                //update some fields with the updated data
                //you can access the data like 'data["driver"]'
            }
        });
    });
});

//the button
<input type="button" id="button" value="Hire!"/>

//update.php
if(isset($_POST['uid'])){
    //connect to the db etc...
    mysql_query("UPDATE  `staff` SET  `driver` =  '3' WHERE `id`='".$_POST['uid']."'") or die(mysql_error());

    //this'll send the new statistics to the jquery code
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT FROM `staff` WHERE `id`='".$_POST['uid']."'")or die(mysql_error());
    $results = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

with "update some fields" in the `success` function of the ajax call, I mean that you can update the statistics on the page which you just changed in the database, so that the statistics on the webpage automatically change in both the database and on the page itself

**Edit**
Put this in the header:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function bye(){
        alert('bye');
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "test1.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {uid: 12341234}, //this sends the user-id to php as a post variable, in php it can be accessed as $_POST['uid']
                success: function(data){
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    //update some fields with the updated data
                    //you can access the data like 'data["driver"]'
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then give your button the id 'button' like this:

```
<form><input type="button" id="button" value="Hire!"/></form>
```

Make sure that the url parameter of the ajax request (`url: "test1.php",`) is pointing to the right php page.

I hope this helped!

**Edit**
This is the code if you want to select a driver:

```
<form><input type="button" class="button" id="3" value="Hire!"/></form> //the id is different for every guy
```

The javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: "test1.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {colID: e.target.id}, //this sends the user-id to php as a post variable, in php it can be accessed as $_POST['uid']
            success: function(data){
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                //update some fields with the updated data
                //you can access the data like 'data["driver"]'
            }
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see, I changed the `#` into a `.`, I added the argument `e` to the callback function and I added the `colID` to the data object.
This'll be the new PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['colID'])){
    //connect to the db etc...

    $colID = mysql_real_escape($_POST['colID']); //for security
    $userID = mysql_real_escape($_SESSION['uid']);
    mysql_query("UPDATE  `staff` SET  `$colID` =  'newValue' WHERE `id`='$userID'") or die(mysql_error());

    //this'll send the new statistics to the jquery code
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT FROM `staff` WHERE `id`='$userID'")or die(mysql_error());
    $results = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

I hope this is what you meant :)

Comment: I used "this.id" Instead of "e.target.id" to pass the id value to ajax.